# Is there an alternative to MIN() that can return the full datetime value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, min

I added a table to the database for our ERP system to track shipdate related information, and I need to identify the first and last datetime entries.  The table is populated by a trigger I have on another table, and gets populated with the datetime the change was written back into the database.

```
SELECT     
TOP (100) PERCENT 
SalesOrder, 
MIN(NewShipDate) AS NewShipDate,
MAX(OldShipDate) AS OldShipDate
FROM dbo.ShipDateHistory
GROUP BY SalesOrder
```

As expected MIN(NewShipDate) returns a minimum value; the issue is there could be multiple entries on the same date, so I was trying to find a way to have it return the full minimum datetime from the table.

The results I see for min() just show the date:

```
000000000172682 2019-01-29  NULL
```

This is correct for the date, however there are two entries in the table for that order on the same date:
Table sample:

```
SalesOrder  OldShipDate NewShipDate LastOperator    ChangeDate  
000000000172682 NULL    2019-01-29  RJB 2019-01-29 09:41:13.150  
000000000172682 NULL    2019-01-29  RJB 2019-01-29 09:41:40.097
```

Ideally I would see the full datetime:

```
000000000172682 2019-01-29 09:41:13.150 NULL
```

Comment: `min()` includes the date *and* time for `datetime` columns.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question to include sample of what I see when min() runs, what exists in my table and how I would like to see the datetime show in the result.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I must have been getting results mixed up, maybe time to leave the screens for a loop around the offices.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this?

```
SELECT
 TOP (100) PERCENT SalesOrder, NewShipDate AS NewShipDate, OldShipDate AS OldShipDate FROM dbo.ShipDateHistory 
where NewShipDate = (Select min(NewShipDate) from dbo.ShipDateHistory group by SalesOrder)
```

Comment: This code gives me the same issue I keep running into; there can, and have been, multiple changes in the same day, but with min() seeming to only return the date it throws an error due to having more than one result returned.

Answer (score 0):

The full datetime is returning; now to work out the other selects.